# How change filter variable in view from Django template?

Tags: django, view, django-templates

I have review model that has reviews made by users. In view I do pagination for it. Then I do filter the reviews by variable `type = 'art'` How i can change variable filter for  `type = 'music'` from template to display selectet reviews? How then use `all()` to display all of them? Do I have to make separate templates for each view variable or is simpler way?

My view.py:

```
def viewrevs(request):
        rev = Reviews.objects.filter(type = 'art')
        paginator = Paginator(rev,2)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
...
```

My template.html

```
{% for rev in page_obj %}
        {{ rev.name }}
        {{ rev.size }}
        {{ rev.data }}
...
{% enfor %}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be like a user search feature for reviews? @Agora99

Comment: If Users can select type of reviews to display by buttons 'art', 'music' etc in template. We can call it search. Its what I try to do. @kwamito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use query paraments like this `domain/search/?type=art`

Your URL can be as such

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('domain/search/', views.CityListView.as_view()),
]
```

Then your views:

```
def viewrevs(request):
    # Grab the type from the query param
    _type = request.GET.get('type','art')
    
    # Filter by the type
    rev = Reviews.objects.filter(type=_type)
    paginator = Paginator(rev,2)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
```

You can even do similar for pagination, have a param for `page_size` and `page`